# how can I set a java script variable equal to another and use its properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

I'm just a beginning programmer. I'm making a program were the user can select objects from one array to be put in another array where a random object is selected and made into a variable . However, I can't seem to use the same properties with my new variable  in the new array.

```
    function verb(first,second,third,fourth,conjugation,chapter) {

    this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
    this.third = third;
    this.fourth = fourth;
    this.conjugation = conjugation;
this.chapter = chapter;
}

var family = new Array();

family[0] = new verb("amo","amare","amavi",'amatum',1,1);
family[1] = new verb("moneo","monere","monitum",2,1);
family[3] = new verb("debeo","debere","debui","debitum",2,1);


for(i=0;i<20;i++) {



    if(chap_beg< i <  chap_end) {
    var randselect  = new Array();   
     randselect.push = family[i];
     var rand = family[Math.floor(Math.random() * family.length)];   

var t = rand.third;
var perfect2 = t.substring(0,(t.length)-2);
```

Comment: THis code had a large number pf problems -- some strange syntax.  Everything from your `push` not doing what you want it to do (it assigns a value to push, overriding the function) to not having a closing brace.

If you could explain what output you were expecting, that would help.

Comment: sorry this is only a subset of the code. The closing brackets are in another part. Anyways I'm look for  a string consisting of the verbs 3rd form.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you skip family[2]? And this part should be like this:

```
randselect.push(family[i]);
var rand = family[Math.round(Math.random() * (family.length - 1))];
```

Comment: sorry what I ment to put in the code was var rand = randselect[Math.floor(Math.random()*randselect.length)];